# Need clarification for java array declaration

Tags: java, arrays

If we do `int[] b = {2, 4};` then we have an array called b, with length 2. From what I understand, the java compiler is implicity doing `int[] b = new int[] {2, 4};` for me, fine.

Similarly, if we do `int[] c = new int[2];` , then we get an array called c initialzed to `{0, 0}` My confusion comes from why the following doesn't work:

Why can't I do `int[] d = new int[2] {5, 6};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a compiler thing. Besides, why would you want to manually input the size anyway?
This will just be a source of error.

The `int[] b = new int[] {2, 4}` notation is for convenience, if you already know the contents of the array that you want to declare.

Comment: +1 - Maybe to partially initialize an array while still giving it a larger size would be my only thought on why it might be helpful if it were actually possible.